# Spring Boot - Rest Controller responds with two JSON objects

Tags: spring-boot, httpresponse

My spring boot rest controller for my login returns two messages instead of one. It returns both the correct object as well as the http response in JSON.

I tried replacing response entity with the object directly, but nothing worked so far. The odd thing is that it works on my local server but on my production server on google it returns as shown below.

```java
@PostMapping("/login")
@Transactional
public JwtAuth login(@Valid @RequestBody Request loginRequest) {
    ....
    return new JwtAuth(jwt);
}
```

Token:

```java
@Data
public class JwtAuth {
    private String accessToken;
    private String tokenType = "Bearer";

    public JwtAuth(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }
}
```

```
{
    "accessToken": "<token>",
    "tokenType": "Bearer"
}{
    "timestamp": "2019-08-01T12:09:09.690+0000",
    "status": 200,
    "error": "OK",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/rest/auth/login"
}
```

I only want to get this as my answer:

```
{
    "accessToken": "<token>",
    "tokenType": "Bearer"
}
```

Comment: How is your client calling this endpoint? Do you get the same response body if you call it using curl or postman?

Comment: Also your response shows the path is `/rest/auth/login` but your controller is using `/signin`, is this a typo or are you perhaps calling the wrong endpoint?

Comment: can you show what is that `token` type?

Comment: @Mike the response comes from Postman actually. I just have a type in this stackoverflow post. Let me edit that.

Comment: @Deadpool Data
public class JwtAuthenticationResponse {
    private String accessToken;
    private String tokenType = "Bearer";

    public JwtAuthenticationResponse(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }
}

Comment: *, noRollbackFor = Exception.class*? Then when you will rollback? Only manually?

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes, manually

Comment: IMHO its as bad as it can be, but thats offtopic.

Comment: @Antoniossss the function actually never fires Exception.class. Its just left over from a copy past. I just needed the Transactional annotation. I will remove rollback

Comment: RuntimeException is subclass of Exception... so you never know - offtopic.,

Comment: Good point. I removed it.

Comment: The concatenation points to a second Stream being written on the response object. I would check whether there is some filter injected in your application that is manipulating the Response object. Can be in your application (we would need to see more of it) or in some external component that exists only on the instance deployed on your production server on Google (how is the application deployed? Is it standalone or is it serverless?). Can you provide us with the pom.xml?

Comment: @FilippoPossenti I think you are onto something. It is a standalone running on Compute Engine with a Nginx in front of it. The odd thing is I have another login method (one for Gmail sign in and one for regular id, passwor login) which does not append anything to the response. The one appending the response verifies an authO token, if this helps by any chance.

Comment: Wrap it inside the ResponseEntity class.

Comment: @MarvinB Your next step is to try and eliminate all intermediaries to your API call one by one, until the one interfering with your code is identified. This means, for example, finding a way to call the API method skipping the nginx instance. This should allow you to identify the portion of software layer that is "misbehaving". Once that is located, add the additional findings to your post so that others can step in and help with more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

In `@RestController` you can simply return entity you would like to serialize, like

```
@PostMapping("/login")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
public JwtAuth signin(@Valid @RequestBody Request loginRequest) {
    JwtAuth token=getTokenSomehow();
    return token;
}
```

If you want to use `Response` (eg if non-rest controller), do it like this

```
public Response signin(@Valid @RequestBody Request loginRequest) {
     JwtAuth token=getTokenSomehow();
     return new Response.ok().entity(token).build();
}
```

Comment: Top one I already tried and it gives me the same result. I will try the bottom one now. Thank you